# check for the correct data in mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a wordpress theme that i'm trying to add some minor security to (prevention from stealing (torrenting, other illegal download methods)).

It's not the best way to prevent the matter but it's a start i guess.

What I'm trying to do is get PHP to hop into a database and check if there are certain values in certain fields. If there are, the server can finish processing the rest of the script. If the data is not correct in the database, a short message will explain the matter and so on.

Now i'm pretty sure this is going to include the "if" function but i have no idea how to get php to just check (not fetch) for the data.

Comment: Do you already know how to fetch the columns from the database you want to check?

Comment: Also: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

Comment: yes, i do. while($my_var = mysql_fetch_array($select)) {
    $name = $my_var["name"];
    $email = $my_var["email"];
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you query **db** with where clause and then check **number of rows** against your query.
If you found number of rows greater than 0 . Then you may proceed otherwise use PHP exit function to stop processing

Answer (score 0):

PHP isn't compiled, so anyone will always be able to view the source and remove any PHP you put in to prevent illegal distribution. Unfortunately, protecting web work is basically impossible.

Comment: hey there. Yes but the theme i' distributing requires certain data for any links on it to work. It's a theme for affiliate marketers, so without links, the themes useless.

Comment: the certain data will be fetched from the database on my own server

Comment: so what i'm trying to do is if the data on the db is not what php is looking for, stop processing the script and throw an error at the user (maybe a redirect). All i need to know is how to actually check for the correct data with php. Thanks